# MySQL insert values only if non exists in unique key combination

Tags: mysql, insert, unique-key, not-exists

in one of my tables, there is a unique key based on two columns. One must be a value (NOT NULL) and the other may be NULL.

For the logic behind the issue, I made this table schema;

```
CREATE TABLE `testinserttable` (
  `RowId` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SomeId` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `UsedForUniqueKey` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RowId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UniqueKey` (`SomeId`,`UsedForUniqueKey`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

and added these values

[image]

now I would like to ONLY add SomeId, when it doesn't exists in the table in whatever combination with UsedForUniqueKey. And, also important, I would like to do this in a bulk.

So, for instance, I would like to bulk add 'Bye','ola','Hi' to the table, if the value does not exist. Bye exists, so this should be skipped.
I have seen working examples with one row, but not with bulk. Any idea on how to get this working in a single statement?

regards,

Matthijs

Comment: Noway in single query form - when you execute INSERT then either all rows are inserted or the whole query fails and none rows are inserted. You'd try INSERT IGNORE which may skip duplicated rows without the query fail but your additional column is nullable, and the row which contains NULL in unique expression is not treated as duplicate.

Comment: Any way to select new values as a table like select and add a join to the existing table only insert where null for the existing table?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/H-K0q3Qu

Comment: Thanks @Akina! I was looking for some kind of solution using 'WITH" but was unable to figure out the MySQL format. I used it in Sql Server. Thanks for the help!

Comment: On SQL Server the only difference is that CTE must be placed before INSERT clause.